# Exception when accessing the Resource Dictionary in Universal platform

Tags: c#, universal

In my project i am setting a tooltip template, i am using the following codes in generic.xaml file

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PART_TooltipTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                Background="LightYellow"
               BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tooltip}" 
                   FontSize="12"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   Padding="2"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

and from my code behind, i am using it as

```
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary(){Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)};
```

While accessing it, i am getting the following Exception
"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

So how can i resolve this problem..??

Thanks in advance:)